# Twitter-Bootstrap Modal on Modal custom close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using the twitter bootstrap framework for web application. I am using a modal in which I call another modal, having 1 modal on top of the other modal. Currently if you click the close 'x' button it closes both modal windows. I only want to close the top modal.

The Modal class Definition starts on line 750 in bootstrap.js.

**Modal HTML**

```
<div class="modal fade hide modal-creator" id="myModal_crop_image" style="display: none;height:600px;" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#myModal_crop_image">×</button>
        <h3>Create New Gallery</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <img style="height:50%;" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>data/001/images/album/014.jpg" alt="" />
    </div><!-- /modal-body -->

    <div class="modal-footer">

</div>
```

**BootStrap JS**

```
!function ($) {

  "use strict"; // jshint ;_;


 /* MODAL CLASS DEFINITION
  * ====================== */

  var Modal = function (element, options) {
    this.options = options
    this.$element = $(element)
      .delegate('[data-dismiss="modal"]', 'click.dismiss.modal', $.proxy(this.hide, this))
    this.options.remote && this.$element.find('.modal-body').load(this.options.remote)
  }

  Modal.prototype = {

      constructor: Modal

    , toggle: function () {
        return this[!this.isShown ? 'show' : 'hide']()
      }

    , show: function () {
        var that = this
          , e = $.Event('show')

        this.$element.trigger(e)

        if (this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

        $('body').addClass('modal-open')

        this.isShown = true

        this.escape()

        this.backdrop(function () {
          var transition = $.support.transition && that.$element.hasClass('fade')

          if (!that.$element.parent().length) {
            that.$element.appendTo(document.body) //don't move modals dom position
          }

          that.$element
            .show()

          if (transition) {
            that.$element[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
          }

          that.$element
            .addClass('in')
            .attr('aria-hidden', false)
            .focus()

          that.enforceFocus()

          transition ?
            that.$element.one($.support.transition.end, function () { that.$element.trigger('shown') }) :
            that.$element.trigger('shown')

        })
      }

    , hide: function (e) {
        e && e.preventDefault()

        var that = this

        e = $.Event('hide')

        this.$element.trigger(e)

        if (!this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

        this.isShown = false

        $('body').removeClass('modal-open')

        this.escape()

        $(document).off('focusin.modal')

        this.$element
          .removeClass('in')
          .attr('aria-hidden', true)

        $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade') ?
          this.hideWithTransition() :
          this.hideModal()
      }

    , enforceFocus: function () {
        var that = this
        $(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
          if (that.$element[0] !== e.target && !that.$element.has(e.target).length) {
            that.$element.focus()
          }
        })
      }

    , escape: function () {
        var that = this
        if (this.isShown && this.options.keyboard) {
          this.$element.on('keyup.dismiss.modal', function ( e ) {
            e.which == 27 && that.hide()
          })
        } else if (!this.isShown) {
          this.$element.off('keyup.dismiss.modal')
        }
      }

    , hideWithTransition: function () {
        var that = this
          , timeout = setTimeout(function () {
              that.$element.off($.support.transition.end)
              that.hideModal()
            }, 500)

        this.$element.one($.support.transition.end, function () {
          clearTimeout(timeout)
          that.hideModal()
        })
      }

    , hideModal: function (that) {
        this.$element
          .hide()
          .trigger('hidden')

        this.backdrop()
      }

    , removeBackdrop: function () {
        this.$backdrop.remove()
        this.$backdrop = null
      }

    , backdrop: function (callback) {
        var that = this
          , animate = this.$element.hasClass('fade') ? 'fade' : ''

        if (this.isShown && this.options.backdrop) {
          var doAnimate = $.support.transition && animate

          this.$backdrop = $('<div class="modal-backdrop ' + animate + '" />')
            .appendTo(document.body)

          if (this.options.backdrop != 'static') {
            this.$backdrop.click($.proxy(this.hide, this))
          }

          if (doAnimate) this.$backdrop[0].offsetWidth // force reflow

          this.$backdrop.addClass('in')

          doAnimate ?
            this.$backdrop.one($.support.transition.end, callback) :
            callback()

        } else if (!this.isShown && this.$backdrop) {
          this.$backdrop.removeClass('in')

          $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade')?
            this.$backdrop.one($.support.transition.end, $.proxy(this.removeBackdrop, this)) :
            this.removeBackdrop()

        } else if (callback) {
          callback()
        }
      }
  }
```

Here is a link to the js. http://jsfiddle.net/dazaweb/5cR95/

Any ideas on how I go about this?

Comment: Just as an FYI, a fiddle with your problem displayed it in would have been much more helpful than one containing the modal javascript, which is probably dependent on other scripts to work.

Comment: thanks @JamesKleeh - just getting started with fiddle. do appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your modal definition where you have `data-dismiss="modal"`, add `data-target="#theIdOfTheModal"`

This will tell it to only close that specific modal

I created a fiddle demonstrating this and it actually works with or without data-target:
[Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/Nv9dd/1/)

Comment: updated question, with your suggestion. still closing both modals

Comment: In your updated post you are missing the # symbol in data-target

Comment: thanks--still closing on me. As a note, when I click on the background surrounding the modal, only the top modal closes leaving the original modal.

Comment: Ok there are bootstrap template JSFiddles out there, just google it. Use those to demonstrate your problem. When you create a fiddle out there post it here so we can easily test solutions.

Comment: ok even i was facing this same error i try using james's solution but it didnt worked out for me as well so i got a another solution which is just a work around but it works fine for me this is how i did it
------------------------------------------------------------------
<div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalid" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                  </div>
----------------------------------------------------------------------
i used same button as closed :) which initiate modal in first place

Answer (score 1):

Add to modal hide method (top most line)

```
e & e.stopPropogation();
```

This will stop from bubbling event to parents and rest of children.

Also, pass event param in `hide()` (so that it becomes `hide(e)`) inside escape method.

Answer (score 1):

1. In cancel and close button remove this: data-dismiss="modal";
2. Then add a class, for example: "close_modal";
3. In javascript create a delegate function like below:

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button:button.close_modal', function ( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(event.currentTarget);
  var modalId = $this.closest('div.modal').attr('id');
  $('#'+modalId+'').modal('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative

```
$('#myModal .close').click();
```